# The point P(k,2k) is equidistant from A(8,11) and B(1,12). Find the value of k.

Tags: geometry

The above question is elf explanatory, but could you help me figure out how to find the value of equidistant points?

Comment: Use $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 +(y_1-y_2)^2}$

Comment: Do you know the formula for the distance between two points? If yes just solve $d(A,P)=d(B,P).$

Comment: Given $(k - 8)^2 + (2k- 11)^2 = (k - 1)^2 + (2k - 12)^2$, this is quadratic in $k$, solve for $k$.

Comment: Another method is to calculate the mid-point between A and B, which is (4.5, 11.5). The line going through this point, perpendicular to the line-segment AB points in the direction (1, 7). Finally check where the line (4.5, 11.5) + C*(1, 7) is equal to the point P, i.e. (k, 2k). You then find that C = -0.5 and k = 4.